# Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is homeomorphic to a one-point compactification of a given set

Tags: general-topology

> Let $B = [0, 1) ∪ [2, 3) ∪ [4, 5) ∪ [6, 7)$ be a locally compact
>   subspace of $\mathbb{R}$
>
> Describe a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is homeomorphic to the
>   one-point compactification $B^+$ of $B$. You do not need to prove that
>   they are indeed homeomorphic.

I'm not sure, how I would tackle this problem. Would I need to describe a homeomorphism between such two sets, or how would I describe such a subspace?

Comment: Maths is a heavy *cross* to bear....

Answer (score 4):

How would you put these four segments in a plane, so that you can "compactificate" the figure adding a single point?

Answer (score 4):

It should have a point $\infty$ which is the limit of sequences approaching $1$ in $[0,1)$, and approaching in $3$ in $[2,3)$, and approaching $5$ in $[4,5)$, and approaching $7$ in $[6,7)$. In other words, all those endpoints need to be identified or the same point.